# How to source database schema before running tests in my Go program

Tags: mysql, sql, database, go

I have to run Go tests for database interactions.
Database Schema is in a **.sql** file.
I have a folder A which has package main and I have 3 folders B, C and D inside A which have package B, C and D respectively. B,C,D have test files in them but A does not have any tests. I want a way so that I just do a

```
go test ./...
```

from A and all my tests run after sourcing schema into mysql.

I tried making a main_test.go file in A and placing a TestMain function there. But it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use init function on `main_test.go`

```
package main

    func init(){
      // load and execute your db schema here. 
    }
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization

the `init()` on main package will be executed on package initialization